# AccessController.doPrivileged() Issue in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to java. I want to run a simple hello world application in eclipse IDE.

```
public class Hello
{
    public static void main( String[] args )    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

I am getting errors in console:

```
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
Could not find the main class: com.tutorialspoint.demo.hr.model.Hello. Program will exit.
```

Comment: This due to security Privilege issue. Can you give OS details.]

Comment: Earlier I installed sap hana cloud platform..

Comment: Check your file. it's have read and write access or not. If not then give the access and then try in eclipse.

Comment: If the permissions are okay and the problem persists, then check that both the JVM and the compiled code are of the shame bit size (32 or 64). This shouldn't ever be a problem from within the GUI, but I guess you never know!?

Comment: Yes the permissions are okay an still the problem exists. How to "  check that both the JVM and the compiled code are of the same bit size (32 or 64). "

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted contains a line

```
"Could not find the main class: com.tutorialspoint.demo.hr.model.Hello"
```

Make sure your class file i.e. `Hello.class` place at this location `"com.tutorialspoint.demo.hr.model.Hello"` while running your program.